# C# delegate variance and generics

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, variance

In the code below, I want to use an action having a more derived parameter pass into an action using the base as a parameter.  The code looks like this:

```
public interface IContext<T>
{
}

public interface IWorkflow<T>
{
    void Do(Action<IContext<T>> lambda);
}


public interface IDerivedContext : IContext<int>
{

}

public interface IDerivedWorkflow : IWorkflow<int>
{
    void Do(Action<IDerivedContext> lambda);
}

public class Workflow<T> : IWorkflow<T>
{
    public void Do(Action<IContext<T>> lambda)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in Do(Action<IContext<T>>");
    }
}

public class DerivedContext : IContext<int>
{
}

public class DerivedWorkflow : Workflow<int>, IDerivedWorkflow
{
    public void Do(Action<IDerivedContext> lambda)
    {
        base.Do(lambda); // Compiler error:
    }
}
```

If I cast this line:

```
        base.Do(lambda);
```

like this:

```
        base.Do((Action<IContext<int>>)lambda);
```

The compiler accepts the cast but code fails at runtime with an InvalidCastException.

Based on the MSDN documentation it suggests that the above should work because I'm passing an Action with a parameter of a more derive class to an Action using a parameter of a least derived class (in this case the base class) for example the docs illustrates the following:

```
static void AddToContacts(Person person)
{
    // This method adds a Person object
    // to a contact list.
}

static void Test()
{
    // Create an instance of the delegate without using variance.
    Action<Person> addPersonToContacts = AddToContacts;

    // The Action delegate expects 
    // a method that has an Employee parameter,
    // but you can assign it a method that has a Person parameter
    // because Employee derives from Person.
    Action<Employee> addEmployeeToContacts = AddToContacts;
 }
```

}

Am I misunderstanding something or is there a workaround to this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fundamentally unsafe; you can't do that.

An `Action<IDerivedContext>` can only take an `IDerivedContext` as a parameter.  Had you been able to convert it to `Action<IContext<int>>`, you would be able to call it with some other `IContext<int>` implementation that it can't actually accept.

Comment: I guess I needed a slap upside the head to wake up. I couldn't see the problem because the scope of issue was narrowed only to this one inheritance example from IContext<T>.  Your answer now helps me see why this is unsafe because there could be a completely disparate inheritance branch extending from IContext<T>.